# iOS swift UIPageViewController with container

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a strange behavior with `UIPageViewController`.
Steps :

1. Open view controller
2. Tap on camera button
3. Choose picture
4. When return back, the included View Controller into the ContainerView take all place in View Controller

Here is my code :

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

```
 class ContainerPagerViewController: BaseUIViewController {

    // The UIPageViewController
    var pageContainer: UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create the page container
        pageContainer = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)

        // Add it to the view
        view.addSubview(pageContainer.view)
    }


}

class RPViewController: BaseUIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var containerViewController: ContainerPagerViewController?

    // Track the current index
    var currentIndex: Int?
    private var pendingIndex: Int?  

    private(set) lazy var pages: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.addViewController(identifier: "ViewController1"),
            self.addViewController(identifier: "ViewController2"),
            self.addViewController(identifier: "ViewController3"),
            self.addViewController(identifier: "ViewController4"),
            self.addViewController(identifier: "ViewController5"),
            self.addViewController(identifier: "ViewController6")]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentIndex = 0

        containerViewController?.pageContainer.delegate = self
        containerViewController?.pageContainer.dataSource = self
  }

  private func addViewController(identifier: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
            instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! UIViewController
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerSegue" {
            containerViewController = segue.destination as? ContainerPagerViewController
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
       return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        pendingIndex = pages.index(of: pendingViewControllers.first! as! UIViewController)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if completed {
                currentIndex = pendingIndex
            }
        }
    }

}
```